# after hiding checkbox still empty space is appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

first i am hiding all displayed `checkboxes` then showing some of them but after showing some for hidden `checkboxes` still empty spaces  appearing

```
// this is hiding checkbox code
$("input[type='checkbox']").parent().hide();

// this is showing checkboxes with value
$("input[value=" + this.themeName + "]").parent().show();

// following is my inspect element
<label style="display: none;"> 
    <input type="radio" value="New Ramy Catalogue-2">
    New Ramy Catalogue-2
</label>

<li style="display: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="COUNTRY">
</li>
```

Comment: Can you show the Html code?

Comment: Yes, need HTML too please

Comment: hide the parent html of them!

Comment: $("#checkboxesFC").append($("<label>").text(myjsonFC[index].featurecataloguename).prepend(
                                    $("<input>").attr('type', 'radio').val(myjsonFC[index].featurecataloguename)
                                    .prop('checked', myjsonFC[index].checked)
                                    ), $("</br>"));

Comment: $("#checkboxesFC").append($("<label>"),  $("<li>").text(myjsonFT[i].definition).prepend(
                                           $("<input>").attr('type', 'checkbox').val(myjsonFT[i].featuretypename)
                                            .prop('checked', myjsonFT[i].checked)
                                            ));

Comment: haha! can you set a snippet on the question? or a jsifiddle.net to show the issue?